# HQL - select results where value is not in inner join

Tags: sql, hql

I'm trying to select all customer ids except for customers who have at least one order of type "d".

I've tried:

```
select customers.id from Customers customers inner join Orders orders on orders.buyerId = customers.id where orders.type != 'd';
```

But this selects all customer ids as long as the customer at least one order that's not type "d".

How can I select all customer ids except for customers who have at least one order of type "d"?

Comment: use not in instead of join. Because 1 customer have more than 1 order. It will only not display the customer with order A for example. But this customer might have order B so it will still show.

Comment: I need to use a subquery?

Comment: check on below, if still not correct maybe u can use sql fiddle to describe ur data and ur expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Inner Join you should use not in like below

```
select customers.id from Customers customers
where customers.id not in (select buyerId from Orders where orders.type = 'd';)
```

So we filter all the customer that have order type "d".
If you use like above you will filter based on the order only, if the same customer have another order the customer id will still display.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT customers.id FROM Customers customers 
LEFT JOIN Orders orders ON orders.buyerId = customers.id AND orders.type = 'd'
WHERE orders.KEY IS NULL
```

Replace orders.KEY with the key field name of the Orders table